# Подключение @media в Less

Tags: css, less

Применяю @media для разных расширений экрана

```
@col-width:8.33333333%;
.col-3{
width:@col-width*3;
}
.col-4{
width:@col-width*4;
}
.col-5{
width:@col-width*5;
}
...
.col-3, .col-4, .col-5{
padding:0 10px;
float:left;
}
.inner{width:960px} 
@media (max-width:992px) and (min-width:768px){
.inner{width:100%!important;}
}
@media (max-width:767px){
.inner{
    width:100%!important;
    min-width:540px;    
}
.col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-8, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12 {
    width:100%!important;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
}
```

Если изменять размер браузера вручную - работает. Но на устройствах с таким расширением (и на chrome device emulator) работает только для 992px-768px, а для  >767px - нет. Less компилируется в браузере. Подскажите почему?

Comment: а что конкретно не срабатывает? возможно, стили для <767рх не перебиваются? посмотрите в отладчик для проверки

Comment: От less в media тут в принципе ничего и нет. Никакие переменные там, миксины и прочие примочки не используются. Код вроде бы написан верно.
Может быть, проблема в компиляции кода в браузере? Попробуйте скомпилировать файл на компе через прогу или онлайн, и прикрепить к документу его. Не понимаю зачем в принципе в браузере компилировать less.